# How to get working a local gem on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems

I have a modified version of the gem declarative authorization on my RoR app.

It's under vendor/gems/declarative_authorization.

My gemfile has

```
gem "declarative_authorization", '= 0.5.5', path: "vendor/gems/declarative_authorization/"
```

It works fine on deployment and testing but when I try to push to heroku, after it runs `bundle install` it gives me an error because it can't find functions provided by that gem. Specifically the method `filter_access_to` can't be found.

`heroku restart` doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got it working.

My solution was use :git instead of :path

```
gem 'gem_name', '= 0.x.x', git: 'git://........../gem_name.git'
```