# "Local" gem not working when deploying with capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, bundler, activeadmin

I'm working on a project needing active_admin gem. But I needed to modify activeadmin :

- I cloned active_admin repo inside a directory I created : `/vendor/gems/`
- Removed .git inside : `/vendor/gems/active_admin/`
- Added the folder to my own git repository
- I modified Gemfile to point to the folder :

  `gem "active_admin", :path => "vendor/gems/active_admin"`

It works great on local development machine: I do `bundle install` and it works fine :

```
Using activeadmin (0.5.0) from source at ./vendor/gems/active_admin
```

But when I do a `cap deploy`, bundle is complaining :

```
 ** [out] Could not find activeadmin-0.5.0 in any of the sources
```

Is there any magic solution ? Should I include activeadmin in another directory like lib and remove it from gemfile ?

Thanks for helping me !

Pof

Comment: Same for me: *** [err :: myserver.com] fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying a git path instead of a local path.

```
gem "active_admin", :git => 'git://........../gem_name.git'
```

I had the same problem deploying to heroku and I got it working specifying a git path instead of a local path. Check: [How to get working a local gem on heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12280684/how-to-get-working-a-local-gem-on-heroku)

Comment: That's what I did, regarding the urgentness of the need, but this split the code in two git repos. What I wanted to do is really include the gem inside my code, because the special activeadmin will only be used in this project...

Comment: I know it's not the best way but I don't know why the other way doesn't work. Maybe a bug...

Answer (score 0):

Bundler v1.2 does grab it from github, see details [here](http://gembundler.com/v1.2/index.html).

Also with bundler you can package your built gems in the repo, without cloning the github repos for them. Just run

```
$ bundle package
$ bundle install
```

in your repo, and commit the gems that bundler adds to the repo.
Alternatively you can use the gem which you build locally putting it in /vendor/cache where all the other ones end up.

Comment: That's irrelevant for my question :D I'm not trying to get or cache a gem from git... I'm trying to use a local gem and make it work when deploying with capistrano.

Comment: I don't think it's irrelevant;) I've been doing it like this, we have a 3 gems that we build locally (or on a build server) for our software and and we bundle them with the repo that goes out to test/staging/production code on deployments. Then capistrano takes care of the rest to install it to the correct ruby version / gemset combo

Comment: Maybe you're right... But the point was to have everything in the same folder. With your solution, there's still multiple folders and gits to manage :D