# Compiling gem after editing it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

rmeetup is one of the only gems available for API for Meetup but is a little outdated
https://github.com/Jberlinsky/rmeetup

I tried to update some of the files on my computer but don't know how to compile them to be used and tested with my app.

Any advice?

Comment: when you are using bundler you can use `path` to point to your local gem version

Answer (score 1):

Besides using bundler with the `path` directive - if you checked out the git project you can run `rake gem` in the `rmeetup` folder. This will create a gem file in the `pkg` folder which you can then install with `gem install`. Now you will have a new system-wide `rmeetup` which includes any changes you made.

You also might want to edit the `Rakefile` to bump the version before you build the new gem.

```
> rake gem
mkdir -p pkg
Gemspec generated
...
> ls pkg
rMeetup-1.0  rMeetup-1.0.gem
```

Comment: Casper, thanks for the response. I been having some trouble getting it to work after doing some edits. Just getting an error I don't know how to solve

Comment: I made the changes to the gem locally and everything works perfectly. I am ready to deploy into production, how can I use my gem? Or in other words, how can i get it onto github to reference it from heroku?

Comment: @MohamedElMahallawy You might want to post a new question on that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12280684/how-to-get-working-a-local-gem-on-heroku

Comment: @MohamedElMahallawy also this: http://underpantsgnome.com/2011/01/06/how-to-install-private-gems-on-heroku